# Why would a member of the Gruul Clans be kicked out?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, ravnica

I'm working on a plot hook to start a new campaign. Originally we were going to do the Ravnica adventure, so my PCs chose a guild... but since we are all new to D&D I decided it would be best to start out with Lost Mines of Phandelver (LMOP.)

Having said that I'm integrating the fact that they were kicked out of their respective guilds into a letter from Gundren Rockseeker asking for their help.

What circumstances would result in a minotaur cleric, or any other member in a more general sense, being removed from the Gruul Clan?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an idea generation question

Comment: What do you mean off topic?

Comment: I didn't catch that you are a new user. Welcome to the stack! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour), and especially check out the [help centre](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where it explains what kinds of questions are "on-topic" here. "On-topic" means that we can probably answer them, as certain kinds of questions, like questions just asking for ideas, have proven unanswerable in a way that works with the system we have. That doesn't mean your question is bad, it just means it doesn't fit here, and there are lots of other places you can ask it.

Comment: Lots of other places... Such as?

Comment: It would something that you could discuss on the [general chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) if you had 20 points of reputation, for example, as brainstorming works better in a chat format where people build on each others' ideas. Otherwise, you may try forums (Giant in the Playground, for example) or Reddit ([r/DnD](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/) for all D&D editions or [r/dndnext](https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/) specifically for 5e).

Comment: How do I get reputation

Comment: *How do I get reputation* Write good question and good answers to questions within the constraints of the Stack Exchange Format.

Comment: Details are here for [questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and here for [answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).  We have a curated list of forums [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566)

Comment: @NautArch yes, there may be a way to frame this more as "here is my problem to solve" but I'll leave the editing to others.  The edit I made was for a bit of grammar/flow.

Comment: Yeah, this more reads to me as "under what circumstances would this possibly occur?" than "suggest to me how I do this."

Comment: A similar question on [Do the Zhentarim fire members for killing fellow members?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147518/do-the-zhentarim-fire-members-for-killing-fellow-members)

Comment: @NautArch It might add more of a focus on the character in question, but I don't think it adds so much to opinion.  I put it back in because it was a OP-provided fact about the situation, and I thought it might be pertinent to the answer.  Organizations often have different rules for clerics, for example, and Minotaurs are largely restricted to the Gruul Clans and the Boros Legion, which might also be meaningful.

Comment: What does the acronym LMOP mean?

Comment: @GcL Lost Mines of Phandalever - it's a published adventure for starting characters

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it strikes me as a classic list-question: the answers are likely to be a boundless list of largely-undifferentiated ideas. Please see [our meta discussions on list questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-questions) for more context and, if voting to reopen, please be sure to comment on how this question doesn't present similarly to those discussed on meta. Thanks!

Comment: @nitsua60 How is this different than [this question on Zhentarim?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147518/do-the-zhentarim-fire-members-for-killing-fellow-members)

Comment: See also [this meta,](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5758/23970) at "Brainstorming."

Comment: @NautArch: It's substantially different, in my opinion. A question that asks "Is this action one that this faction punishes people for?" can be answered with "yes, here's where it's stated that it's forbidden", "no, here's where it's disallowed", or "there's no guidance provided regarding this". This question, on the other hand, is basically asking answerers to come up with an unbounded list of reasons why one *might* be kicked out of the Gruul Clans.

Comment: In contrast, if the question asked "Is there an official set of rules one must follow to be in the Gruul Clans?", that might be answerable by pointing to an official resource listing the "rules of Gruul" :P ...Of course, that might not get OP the answer they want.)

Comment: @v2blast I really hope you set up those comments just to get to Rule of Gruul :)

Comment: @NautArch: I didn't set them up for it... But I saw my opportunity for the pun and took it :P

Answer (score 1):

> As a collection of disparate clans, the Gruul have no single leader and no headquarters. But the Gruul respect strength and are willing to follow a strong individual who points them in a direction they want to go anyway. - *Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica*, p.58

Gruul is difficult or impossible to actually get kicked out of in a technical sense, because it's a distributed collection of individuals and bands with no guildhall or central leadership with the authority to revoke your membership. How do you get *thrown out* of a group that's *defined* by anarchy and individualism?

You could get thrown out of a specific clan if you upset the clan leader (or upset somebody who convinces them to get rid of you), but realistically, nothing stops you from immediately joining another clan, unless the old clan's leader is strong enough and respected enough to make other local clans wary of allowing you in.

So it's more likely you've done something that angered your clan leader enough to declare you outcast, but not enough to get your head crushed (which might be a tricky tightrope); or you *have* made them mad enough for head-crushing and had to run for your life. You may need to just stay out of the Gruul-controlled areas until said leader gets replaced (or you find something worth trading for your sorry life). Borborgymos, the closest thing Gruul has to a guildmaster, is the obvious choice here, and would explain why all the clans hate you rather than just one, but any of them could potentially work.

Or it could be doctrinal. Where do your clerical powers come from? Usually in Ravnica, it's devotion to an ideal or philosophy. Maybe that source is at odds with Gruul philosophy in some way that makes your exile more self-imposed, at least until you can find a way to harmonize the two sides of yourself.

Comment: Can you add some support to these statements about Gruul? Where is your information from?

Comment: Just what's in the GGtR.

Comment: Okay, so can you cite the passages in GGtR that support all that?

Comment: If by "all that" you mean the first paragraph, yes.  The rest is just suggested paths to exile.